# How to zoom all markers in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapping

This is the code I have to show the markers on the map:

```js
var coordinates = data;

for (var i = 0; i < coordinates.length; i++) {
    if (coordinates[i].x && coordinates[i].y) {
        var marker = L.marker([coordinates[i].x, coordinates[i].y])
                                .bindPopup("Device: " + coordinates[i].device_type + '<br>' + "Time: " + coordinates[i].datetime)
                                .addTo(map);
    }
}
```

It's working, but I can't zoom to view all markers in the window when I refresh the page.

I tried:

```js
map.fitBounds(coordinates.getBounds());
```

But it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your code to:

```
var fg = L.featureGroup();
fg.addTo(map)
var coordinates = data;
                for (var i = 0; i < coordinates.length; i++) {
                    if (coordinates[i].x && coordinates[i].y) {
                        var marker = L.marker([coordinates[i].x, coordinates[i].y])
                            .bindPopup("Device: " + coordinates[i].device_type + '<br>' + "Time: " + coordinates[i].datetime)
                            .addTo(fg);
                    }
                }



map.fitBounds(fg.getBounds());
```

Comment: I got error: Bounds are not valid
Maybe I can make markers group?

Comment: I checked again, my bad. It's fine.